# Git удаленный репозиторий

Tags: git

Привет всем! Подскажите пожалуйста. Только учусь работать с git. У меня на хостинге лежит сайт, и там же репозиторий. Как я могу сделать, что бы делать коммиты, да и вообще работать с проектом не через консоль, а через gui? Я установил SourceTree, клонировал мою репу с хоста. На хосте что то поменял, загрузил на пк, но изменений не вижу, а вижу только коммиты сделанные через консоль на сервере.

Comment: Не все хостинги дают полные права на работу с git. Возможно,  в этом проблема

Comment: @КириллЖелнов, точнее не все хостинги *поддерживают* git.

Comment: @Максим, для самообучения можете использовать [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Если коротко git pull забрать изменения с сервера, git push отправить изменения на сервер.. Но могут быть настройки при которых эта процедура будет сложнее.. 
Рекомендую почитать "Магия Git"  (есть на русском)

Небольшой интерактивный тренажер   https://try.github.io